# undefined main during linking but defined during full compilitaion process

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I am novice in C programming. So I learned different process of compilation(preproccessing, compiling, linking). My program is

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define testDefinition(x) printf(#x " is equal to %lf\n",x)

int main(void)
{
    testDefinition(3.15);
    return 0;
}
```

It is simple program which doesn't have any sense,but problem is when I use `gcc -o test test.c`  it works fine, but when I do that

```
gcc -E test.c -o test.i
gcc -C test.i -o test.o
gcc  test.o -o test
```

I get error

```
usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: in function `_start':
(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and GCC compiler.

Comment: Just use an IDE and let it handle peripheral tasks like build issues for you. Manual make files and command line building is 1990s style programming. It's nostalgia at best and masochism at worst.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but to understand all process completely, how does it work uder "car hood" you should go thourgh this processes. I am studying and it is not real world-wide project when you must use all featetures and facilities of IDEs to simplify work pipeline.

Comment: This isn't "under the hood", that would be machine code. This is rather "go to the car factory of brand x and ask them about which steps they are using when building one of their specific car models". But knowing that holds no practical interest to a car mechanic and it will no help them when they switch to another car brand (tool chain). Just let them build the car as they like and trust them to do their job.

Comment: I don't agree with you, because when you just click run in the IDE you have no idea what compiler is. When you start doing it yourself you start understanding that there are more processes than just clicking run button. Of course it is not very deep level of comprehesion on working process of compilation,but  again it is better that just clicking run button in Visual Studio or any IDE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`test.o` is already the executable, you did not pass `-c`.

```
$ gcc -E test.c -o test.i
$ gcc -C test.i -o test.o
$ ./test.o
3.15 is equal ....
```

Because of it, `test.o` is an ELF file and `gcc` treats it as shared library (I think). Because there are no source files passed in `gcc  test.o -o test` there is no `main`, so it's undefined.

I guess, you wanted to do `gcc -C -c test.i -o test.o` to create an object file.

Comment: Thank you, I got it almost completely)))).